# Spring.net ContextRegistry.GetContext fails with 2 interface implementations

Tags: dependency-injection, spring.net

I have a `.net application`, that uses Spring.net. 
Also there are 2 implementations of one `interface`. Which one should be used - it is based on `configuration file`.

The `bootstrap` for Spring has

```
<objects>
 <object id="Impl1" name="Impl1" type="namespace.Impl1, IInterface" >
  </object>
  <object id="Impl2" name="Impl2" type="namespace.Impl2, IInterface" >   
  </object>
</objects>
```

It fails on

```
var appContext = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
```

The error message is:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in
>   Spring.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through
>   constructor argument with index 2 of type [namespace.IInterface] : No
>   unique object of type [namespace.IInterface] is defined : expected
>   single matching object but found 2:
>   System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another configuration,  where autowire setting was set as autodetect.

```
<object id="workspaceExportService" type="namespace.Imp3, Namespace"
          autowire="autodetect" />
```

This class `Imp3` has a constructor with `IInterface` parameter. So, It tries to resolve the implementation of `IInterface`, but find two of them.

As a solution, you can add `lazy-init="true"` attribute to object node.